# How do I filter a list of article by category on Django template

Tags: jquery, django, filter, orm

I have a list of `articles` (that has a Many-to-many relationship with `categories`).

I also have `list_articles = Articles.objects.filter(author_id = author_id)`

Now, on template I show `list_articles`.

My question is: How do I quick filter that `list_articles` by click on one category on a sidebar? Which is possible: javascript or python?

Comment: You achieve this using JS(ajax call)

Comment: show your models and code-that is fetching the data from db and sending back to the template.